# Replace ARM Template with Terraform and deploy with Visual Studio

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template

I am able to prepare the main.tf file comprising of my resources to be built on Azure ( Resource Group, Data Lake, Storage Account, data factory ) but need to replace it within the existing Visual Studio solution having ARM template defined. Post that need to deploy and execute the terraform file from VS but not sure how to do it .

Can someone please guide towards it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no extension/integration of Terraform for Visual Studio (only for [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform)).

If you really need to trigger it from Visual Studio, an option would be to use the [integrated terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019), but that would be the same as using an isolated Powershell or CMD terminal window.